# Layout of Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, fancyhdr

I would like to customize the layout of my toc. I want the first page of the toc to look like the other pages (i.e., the header "Contents" shoud be removed, the headline should be like the one on the second page and the toc should start at the top of the page). How can this be done?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhead{}
    \setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
    \def\chaptermark#1{\markboth{\footnotesize\thechapter.\ \textsc{#1}}{}}
    \fancyhead[CO,CE]{\leftmark}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter}
\chapter{Chapter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the `tocloft` package.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
%% set parameters of "fancy" page style
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

%% tocloft package for easy customization of ToC
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\contentsname{}
\tocloftpagestyle{fancy}
\setlength\cftbeforetoctitleskip{0pt}
\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{0pt}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter % optional
%% page header for ToC: set up via '\chead'
\chead{\footnotesize\textsc{Contents}}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter % or: \cleardoublepage
%% page headers for rest of document: use \chaptermark and \fancyhead
\def\chaptermark#1{\markboth{\footnotesize\thechapter.\ \textsc{#1}}{}}
\fancyhead[CO,CE]{\leftmark}

\chapter{The First Chapter}
\chapter{The Second Chapter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I had to adjust the values for `\cftbeforetoctitleskip` and `\cftaftertoctitleskip` but know it works, thank you

Comment: @Martin - Just out of curiosity (and for the potential benefit of future readers of this posting): Which values did you select for these two parameters?

Comment: I choose `-30pt`for both. Then the toc starts approximately at the same height as on the subsequent pages